# How to find Computer name using Sql Profiler?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

For example Microsoft Sql Server installed in Server A. For ServerA there may be many clients. if a client access any database of server A thru statement or stored procedure ,i need to find client Machine Name  using SQL Server Profiler.

Comment: This is filter `Hostname`

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri, just want to add that the HostName reported by Profiler/SQL Trace/Extended Events can be overridden in the client connection string.

Comment: But Hostname Column always shows Server Name not Client Machine name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the execution DMVs, host_name is in sys.dm_exec_sessions:

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_sessions
select * from sys.dm_exec_connections
```

A common query (from MSDN) to give you connection info:

```
SELECT c.session_id, c.net_transport, c.encrypt_option, 
    c.auth_scheme, s.host_name, s.program_name, 
    s.client_interface_name, s.login_name, s.nt_domain, 
    s.nt_user_name, s.original_login_name, c.connect_time, 
    s.login_time 
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections AS c
JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions AS s
    ON c.session_id = s.session_id
```